# MySQL Database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am building a fantasy football application where i have a table that stores all players . I have design the table as shown below . So far the system works when the formation is 4-4-2 where one goalkeeper is out , one defender is out and one forward is out and making changes to the squad is as easy as switching the players inside with the one on the bench .

[image]

The problem comes because i want to have multiple formations like 3-5-2 , 5-4-1 and so forth , i don't know how to save this to the database so as when  someone view the changed team , he can see for example two defenders out when formation is 3-5-2 . I already achieved the frontend using javascript , the issue is the backend . Any help will be appreciated as i run out of options .

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you want, but a good start might be to make a seperate table for formations. Then limit which of these formations you can select, using front-end code.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for helping . Make sense , but if you have a separate table for formation , how will you know which players are on the bench ? that's the biggest challenge i have where if it is 4-4-2 formation its easy to spot by looking at GK2 , DEF5 , MID5 and FWD3 as players on the bench....

Comment: hmm, why don't you make 'position' table that contains GK1, GK2, DEF1, DEF2, etc.. and one table for the football players then make a pivot table (many-to-many relationship) to relate position and players table? regarding 'bench' player, you had to put them into special 'position', like Bench1, Bench2 -- or you each bench related to each position?

Comment: Also, you can still have an active formation on a team, by having a field with the ID of the formation. I.e. one team can have one formation, but one formation can be used by many teams.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. You could store a second record for the same team and another formation. What exactly keeps you from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be using the following tables

```
user
id | team_name | current_formation_id
 1 | Masaki    | 1
 2 | Other     | 3

formation
id | desc | defenders_count | midfielders_count | forwarders_count
 1 | 442  | 4               | 4                 | 2
 1 | 433  | 4               | 3                 | 3
 1 | 352  | 3               | 5                 | 2

player
id | name | role | whatever_else
 1 | P1   | MID  | ...
 2 | P2   | DEF  | ...
 3 | P3   | FWD  | ...

user_roster
user_id | player_id | is_on_field
      1 |         1 | 1
      1 |         2 | 0
      1 |         3 | 1
```

This way you could have the flexibility of changing the formation without altering the tables structure, you could know with a simple query which players are on the bench and which are playing, and you could also easily check if the current players respect the current formation counts.

Comment: Hi , Thanks a  lot . It's probably what i was looking for :-)